# Unable to save the replaced string into the workbook

Tags: python, openpyxl

After replacing a string in the workbook.the replaced string is not reflecting in the workbook.

```
import os, sys, re
from re import *
from openpyxl import *

f='C:/Python3/CODES/output.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(f)

for sheet in wb:
    #print ("\n")
    print ("checking sheet:", sheet)

    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=0,max_row=2):
            for col in sheet.iter_cols(min_col=0,max_col=1):
                for cell in row:
                    cv=cell.value
                    str_input1 = r"Safety"
                    re.search(str_input1 ,str(cv))
                    rep = str(cv).replace("Safety","1pc")

                    wb.save('C:/Python3/CODES/output10.xlsx')
```

No error message. "rep" contains the exact value what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, all you're doing is reading the cell contents into a variable, and then changing that variable. `cv` is not a reference to the cell, you're creating a new string.

The last `for` loop in your code should read something like this:

```
for cell in row:
    cv=cell.value
    str_input1 = r"Safety"
    re.search(str_input1 ,str(cv))
    rep = str(cv).replace("Safety","1pc")
    cell.value = rep # Add this line

...
# This should not be in your loop
wb.save('C:/Python3/CODES/output10.xlsx')
```

Another thing that's worth noting is your `re.search` is not doing anything. All it does is return a match object, and you're not even checking its results. If you want to conditionally replace "Safety" with "1pc", you can simply remove these two lines:

```
str_input1 = r"Safety"
re.search(str_input1 ,str(cv))
```

EDIT: And as was pointed out in the comments, I've moved the `wb.save` out of the for loop. You should only save it after you've made all your changes, not every time you change a cell.

Comment: Ahndwoo, Thank you so much for your help. code is working fine now.